# Android - Timed UI events (with pause/resume)

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I am looking to create timed events which trigger UI changes (like a Toast) on Android. I already know you can do this with a `Handler` object's `postDelayed(runnable, timeDelay)` method ([see this page for a great example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)).

Here is the twist: **I also need to be able to pause and resume the countdown for these events**. So when a user pauses the on-screen timer it also pauses the countdown before each of these events trigger.

One approach that came to mind was to create a `Handler` object on a new `Thread` (not the UI thread) and queue up my events using `postDelayed`; then I would pause or resume this entire `Thread`'s execution using [this method](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html) as needed. The main problem here is figuring out how to make the events run on the UI thread after they have been triggered.

The only other way I can think of would be to check every second that the timer ticks against a list of all my events (brute force) on the UI thread, which is very messy.

If anyone has any thoughts on this or solutions, that would be great!

Comment: I just tried the new Thread with a Handler in it, and it gave me the error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". So it looks like that approach is out the window.

Comment: Did you call Looper.prepare() in that?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all events need to be paused the same amount of time, you could keep track of how much pause time accumulated and, on the handleMessage, re-post using another postDelayed with that delay time.

Some logic would need to be added to make sure you delay them all the proper amount.  For example, if a new event was added into the queue while the game was paused, you wouldn't want to re-post it delayed by the entire pause amount.

You could combine your idea (a queue of events with desired start times). Update that start time when the pause ends. Use a single event that is "processQueue" - set it to only fire when you think the next event should happen. If the time the next event should happen is delayed due to a pause, you can remove the "processQueue" event and re-post it.

Comment: Yes, all of my events would be paused the same amount of time. Thanks for the helpful response! You have come up with what looks like a pretty elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. To be able use a handler with your own thread you need to have a looper see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) for an example
2. To be able to run a command in UI Thread you can pass a Handler reference inside your own thread code to be able to post messages to it.
   Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really look into the Looper class before, but it looks like it would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`Handler#removeCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) will let you un-schedule a posted Runnable. You can post it again later when you know the new time at which it should run.

Comment: Yeah, but I would have to know how much time was left on the original runnable to know what to re-post it as. That wouldn't really jive with the whole "fire and forget" idea too well.